# Db2 on Cloud connection refused w/ reason "19" ("USERID DISABLED or RESTRICTED")

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

While working with my database today, which is a DB2 on Cloud instance (free/lite plan), it began to reject my attempts to connect (from both python and node.js) with the following error:

> SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "19" ("USERID DISABLED or RESTRICTED").  SQLSTATE=08001\r SQLCODE=-30082

The userid in question is the auot-generated user/schema created when I created the Db2 on Cloud service via the console. I and still access the Db2 instance UI from the console. I had able to connect to the database multiple times only a few minutes prior. I have been using the secure (SSL) connection string details. Any ideas on how to reset the userid?

Comment: When did you create the instance? Was your instance migrated over the past days?

Comment: Hi @data_henrik, thank you for reaching out. The instance was created over a year ago. Yes, it _was_ migrated over the past few days. After the migration, I was able to successfully connect using the new SSL connection string approach (new host, port, etc.) for a few hours yesterday before this error started to show up.

Comment: You can get better "admin" answers at dba.stackexchange.com.